# use mysql in ror insted of sqlite3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line

I want to use MySQL in ROR.
I add gem in my **Gem file**.

```
gem mysql2
```

and then I run a command

```
gem install mysql2
```

It gives me following error

> ```
> "could not find a valid gem '0.3.13' <> =0> in any repository"
> ```

Please anybody tell me how can i use MySQL for ROR application

Thanks

Comment: try using the git path https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2

Comment: delete file Gemfile.lock and then run `bundle install`

Answer (score 1):

I think your syntax in your Gemfile is missing quote marks:

```
gem 'mysql'
```

and then your commandline call to install it should instead be:

```
bundle install
```